# TFS access rights for revoking some rights to project collection admins

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).
I have to create some Project Collection Administrators only for administrative purpose.
At the same time, there will be few projects where all the administrators will not have all rights to those projects.
Since rights are inherited, rights cannot be revoked from those administrators and given to some normal users only, few of those users may be project collection administrators also.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible, because with project collection administrator’s permission, he can reset the permission what he needs and add himself to any group of the collection or team project.

So, if other administrator grant deny permission for him, he still can reset these permissions to allow.

To conclude, you can’t add them to project collection administrator group, just grant necessary permission for them.